# How to remove this error: AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no property 'colour'

Tags: python, python-3.x, undefined, nameerror

I'm trying to simulate a music stage in Python, and I keep coming across this error when trying to add lights to the stage. This is my code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

class Light:
    def __init__(self, colour, position, direction, intensity, distribution):
    self.colour = colour
    self.position = position
    self.direction = direction
    self.intensity = intensity
    self.distribution = distribution

def calculate_cone(self):
    spread_angle = math.radians(self.distribution)
    half_cone_angle = spread_angle/2
    start_angle = self.direction - half_cone_angle
    end_angle = self.direction + half_cone_angle

class Stage:
    def __init__(self, figsize=(10,10)):
        self.fig, (self.ax0, self.ax1)=plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 10]}, figsize = (10,10))
        self.ax0.set_aspect("equal")
        self.ax0.fill([0,500,500,0],[0,0,50,50],'k')
        self.ax1.set_aspect("equal")
        self.ax1.fill([0,500,500,0],[0,0,500,500],'k')
        self.title=("STAGEVIEW")
        self.lights=[]
        self.smoke_machines=[]

def add_circle(self, centre, radius, colour):
    circle=plt.Circle(centre, radius)
    self.ax0.add_patch(circle)

    def add_circle(self, centre, radius, colour): 
        circle=plt.Circle(centre, radius) 
        self.ax0.add_patch(circle) 

    def add_light(self, light): 
        self.lights.append(light) 
        spread=np.array(light.distribution) 
        self.ax1.fill(spread[:,0], spread[:,1], colour=light.colour, alpha=0.5) 

    def simulate_lights(self): 
        for lights in self.lights: 
            light.calculate_cone() 

    def show(self): 
        plt.suptitle(self.title, fontsize="18") 

stage = Stage() 
stage.add_circle([50,25],20, 'steelblue') 
stage.add_circle([150,25],20, 'lightblue') 
stage.add_circle([250,25],20, 'steelblue')
stage.add_circle([350,25],20, 'lightblue')
stage.add_circle([450,25],20, 'steelblue')

    lights = [Light(colour="red",position[250,490],direction=90,intensity=1,distribution=[[230,490],[270,490], [270,500],[230,500]])]

for light in lights: 
    stage.add_light(light) 
    stage.simulate_lights() 

stage.show()
```

I tried to add a light to my stage, and thought I'd be able to see it in matplotlib, but keep getting this error:
I have changed the light class to the correct class, but now I get a big error message regarding polygon colours.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "samplestage(1).py", line 75, in <module>
        stage.add_light(light)
      File "samplestage(1).py", line 56, in add_light
        self.ax1.fill(spread[:,0], spread[:,1], colour=light.colour, alpha=0.5)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5037, in fill
        patches = [*self._get_patches_for_fill(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 216, in __call__
        yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 364, in _plot_args
        for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 364, in <listcomp>
         for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 307, in _makefill
    seg.set(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1101, in set
        return self.update(props)
       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1006, in update
        ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1006, in <listcomp>
         ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1002, in _update_property
        .format(type(self).__name__, k))
    AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no property 'colour'
```

I am not sure what to do with this error. I am going to be trying to add multiple lights, to match the circles on the 'stage', but I cannot even get one light to work.

I appreciate the help.

I'm just learning Python, so it can be hard to me to see where I went wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your code instead of a picture

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how to! I'm trying to google that now.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make sense. Please fix.

Comment: I am able to debug the `AttributeError` for Polygon, whereas I am getting another issue at `simulate_lights` and `calculate_cone`, in the latter function, you're using `math.radians` with a 4x2 list, but it takes only an integer argument. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with the functions, as they aren't updating or returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out now, it is "color" not "colour".
Also I change some codes, you can check it like:

```
spread_angle = np.radians(self.distribution)
...
self.ax1.fill(spread[:,0], spread[:,1], color=light.colour, alpha=0.5)
...
plt.show()
plt.close()
# stage.show()
```

the whole codes is here

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

class Light:
    def __init__(self, colour, position, direction, intensity, distribution):
        self.colour = colour
        self.position = position
        self.direction = direction
        self.intensity = intensity
        self.distribution = distribution

    def calculate_cone(self):
        spread_angle = np.radians(self.distribution) #np.array([math.radians(i) for i in self.distribution])
        half_cone_angle = spread_angle / 2
        start_angle = self.direction - half_cone_angle
        end_angle = self.direction + half_cone_angle

class Stage:
    def __init__(self, figsize=(10,10)):
        self.fig, (self.ax0, self.ax1)=plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 10]}, figsize = (10,10))
        self.ax0.set_aspect("equal")
        self.ax0.fill([0,500,500,0],[0,0,50,50],'k')
        self.ax1.set_aspect("equal")
        self.ax1.fill([0,500,500,0],[0,0,500,500],'k')
        self.title=("STAGEVIEW")
        self.lights=[]
        self.smoke_machines=[]

    def add_circle(self, centre, radius, colour):
        circle=plt.Circle(centre, radius)
        self.ax0.add_patch(circle)

    def add_light(self, light): 
        self.lights.append(light) 
        spread=np.array(light.distribution) 
        self.ax1.fill(spread[:,0], spread[:,1], color=light.colour, alpha=0.5) 

    def simulate_lights(self): 
        for lights in self.lights: 
            lights.calculate_cone() 

    def show(self): 
        plt.suptitle(self.title, fontsize="18") 

stage = Stage() 
stage.add_circle([50,25],20, 'steelblue') 
stage.add_circle([150,25],20, 'lightblue') 
stage.add_circle([250,25],20, 'steelblue')
stage.add_circle([350,25],20, 'lightblue')
stage.add_circle([450,25],20, 'steelblue')

lights = [Light(colour="red",position=[250,390],direction=90,intensity=1,distribution=[[230,390],[270,390], [270,500],[230,500]])]

for light in lights: 
    stage.add_light(light) 
    stage.simulate_lights() 

plt.show()
plt.close()
# stage.show()
```

this is result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the `colour` attribute of the `Light` class.

But instead of using `light.colour`, you're using `self.colour`, which references the class `Stage`, which does not have the `colour` attribute, thus raising this error.

Updating your `add_light` method from this:

```py
def add_light(self, light):
    self.lights.append(light)
    spread=np.array(light.distribution)
    self.ax1.fill(spread[:,0], spread[:,1], colour=self.colour, alpha=0.5)
```

to this:

```py
def add_light(self, light):
    self.lights.append(light)
    spread=np.array(light.distribution)
    self.ax1.fill(spread[:,0], spread[:,1], colour=light.colour, alpha=0.5)
```

would solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Antoine, I've updated my code and have edited my above code to show the new error message. Are you able to help me clarify what it is I have done incorrectly? Thanks.